# Chartkick/Rails: Build line_chart using data from an object instead of a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm trying to draw a simple line_chart using data retrieved from an API, but the documentation examples only use data from regular ActiveRecord Model and I'm struggling  a lot. Since I'm not operating over a Model I can't use any of the methods explained in the docs (group etc)

I have this call to a REST API, I got an object with two attributes (there are a few more, but these two are the ones I'm interested at this point), ORDER_CODE and LEAD_TIME. I just want to display a line_chart with the order_codes in the X axis and the lead_times in the Y axis.

My controller code is like that, I use Dish to convert the hash from Json.parse into an object. The API call is working and I'm using the data succesfully in my app.

`leadtimes =  Dish(JSON.parse RestClient.get(ENV['API'], params: { PART: @order.PART }))`

And in the view:

```
<%= line_chart @data%>
```

I was trying this, but I just got an empty chart:

```
@data = leadtimes.map do |value|
  [
    order_code: value.ORDER_CODE, lead_time: value.LEAD_TIME
  ]
end
```

The JSON I got from the API looks like this:

```
[{"ORDER_CODE"=>519805, "PART"=>"00049", "LEAD_TIME"=>29, "DATE"=>"2015-03-03T00:00:00"}, {"ORDER_CODE"=>517297, "PART"=>"00149", "LEAD_TIME"=>54, "DATE"=>"2014-11-26T00:00:00"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working by using the collect method over the original array of hashes contained in the variable leadtimes as shown in the OP.

```
@data = leadtimes.collect{|i| [i['ORDER_CODE'], i['lead_time']]}
```

Just passing @data as an argument to line_chart the chart gets drawn correectly.